# Boost statechart - pass event data to state constructor using triggering_event

Tags: c++, boost, boost-statechart

I would like to be able to communicate the data from an event to a state that gets constructed as a result of a transition.

From [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/boost-list/x4hZtIf41iE/dpneGNoWhWAJ) post in 2009 and [this](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/statechart-Passing-parameters-from-event-to-State-Local-Storage-td2590845.html#a2590848) one in 2010 the use of `triggering_event()` is suggested. However, I can't find an example anywhere that demonstrates how to use it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The following example is a Boost statechart implementation based on the motor state machine described [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/state-machine-design-in-c/184401236).  Instead of using a custom_reaction to pull the speed out of the EvSetSpeed event (as in other states here), I've modified it to call triggering_event() in the constructor of the Start state.

Things to note:

1. The older documentation for boost statechart [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/statechart/doc/future_and_history.html) states: "the caller of triggering_event needs to make a type check or cast the return value", as triggering_event returns a const event_base pointer.
2. Calling triggering_event during construction requires that the calling state derive from state, not simple_state.  This is because triggering_event is accessing the state machine from the constructor.  For what its worth, I also noted the documentation states that the use of triggering_event often implies a problem with the state machine design and should be avoided.
3. Perhaps someone more familiar with boost statechart can comment on this, but I found I had to re-post the triggering event in the Start state constructor if I wanted it to transition to Running (as my reaction list states).

Finally, it's worth mentioning that trying to call triggering_event in the constructor of the initial state of a state machine will result in a null return value.  This is because the initial state is constructed during the call to initiate, where there is no triggering event.

```
#include <boost/statechart/state_machine.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/simple_state.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/state.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/event.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/in_state_reaction.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/transition.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <boost/statechart/custom_reaction.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
namespace sc = boost::statechart;

class EvHalt : public sc::event< EvHalt > {};
class EvSetSpeed : public sc::event< EvSetSpeed >
{
public:
    EvSetSpeed(int speed) : _speed(speed) {}
    int getSpeed() const { return _speed; };

private:
    int _speed;
};

class Idle;
class Start;
class Stop;
class Running;

class Motor : public sc::state_machine<Motor, Idle> {};

class Idle : public sc::simple_state<Idle, Motor>
{
public:
    typedef mpl::list<
        sc::transition< EvSetSpeed, Start >,
        sc::transition< EvHalt, Idle > > reactions;

    Idle() { std::cout << "Entering Idle State" << std::endl; };
    ~Idle() { std::cout << "Exiting Idle State" << std::endl; };
};

class Start : public sc::state<Start, Motor>
{
public:
    typedef mpl::list<
        sc::transition< EvSetSpeed, Running >,
        sc::transition< EvHalt, Stop  > > reactions;

    Start(my_context ctx) : _speed(0), my_base(ctx)
    { 
        auto trigEvt = dynamic_cast<const EvSetSpeed*>(triggering_event());
        if (trigEvt) // returns true if trigEvt is indeed an EvSetSpeed event
        {
            _speed = trigEvt->getSpeed();
            post_event(*trigEvt);
            std::cout << "Entering Start State at speed " << _speed << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Entering Start State. Triggering Event is NOT EvSetSpeed." << std::endl;
    };
    ~Start() { std::cout << "Exiting Start State" << std::endl; };
private:
    int _speed;  // Unused in this example.
};

class Running : public sc::simple_state<Running, Motor>
{
public:
    typedef mpl::list<
        sc::custom_reaction< EvSetSpeed >,
        sc::custom_reaction< EvHalt  > > reactions;

    sc::result react(const EvSetSpeed& ev)
    {
        std::cout << "In Running Mode: Set Speed to " << ev.getSpeed() << std::endl;
        return discard_event();
    }
    sc::result react(const EvHalt& ev)
    {
        std::cout << "In Running Mode: Halting Motor" << std::endl;
        post_event(ev);
        return transit<Stop>();
    }

    Running() { std::cout << "Entering Running State" << std::endl; };
    ~Running() { std::cout << "Exiting Running State" << std::endl; };
};

class Stop : public sc::simple_state<Stop, Motor>
{
public:
    typedef sc::transition< EvHalt, Idle > reactions;

    Stop() { std::cout << "Entering Stop State" << std::endl; };
    ~Stop() { std::cout << "Exiting Stop State" << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    Motor myMotor;
    myMotor.initiate();
    myMotor.process_event(EvSetSpeed(100));
    myMotor.process_event(EvSetSpeed(200));
    myMotor.process_event(EvHalt());
    myMotor.process_event(EvSetSpeed(300));
    myMotor.process_event(EvHalt());
    myMotor.process_event(EvHalt());
    return 0;
}
```